# How do I split a (.csv) file by the number of rows but keeping the first row (column titles) on each split child file? python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been trying to create this python csv splitter based on a solution that I found.

The first issue is keeping the first row (column titles) in each child slipt. It does nott keep the first row as a "header" in each file split.

The second issue is that I'm trying to send the splitted files to a subdirectory that the script creates. It does finds the directory but it stops at the first split, it does not continue the split loop like before, while I was leaving it on the root folder.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Here's the script:

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd


# csv file name to be read in
in_csv = 'D:path\\test.csv'

# get the number of lines of the csv file to be read
number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(in_csv)))

# size of rows of data to write to the csv,

# you can change the row size according to your need
rowsize = 100


# start looping through data writing it to a new file for each set
for i in range(0, number_lines, rowsize):

    df = pd.read_csv(in_csv,
                     nrows=rowsize,  # number of rows to read at each loop
                     skiprows=i)  # skip rows that have been read
    # Subdir maker
    directory = 'output'
    parent_dir = 'path\\rows'

    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
    os.mkdir(path)
    print('Directory created.\n')

    time.sleep(2)

    # csv to write data to a new file with indexed name. input_1.csv etc.
    out_csv = os.path.join(path, 'NewFile' + str(i) + '.csv')

    print('Initiating slicer...')
    time.sleep(2)

    df.to_csv(out_csv,
              index=False,
              header=True,
              mode='a',  # append data to csv file
              chunksize=rowsize)  # size of data to append for each loop
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `pandas`, but I've done some CSV stuff with pure Python and it always works out. Here's a version of what I think you're trying to do with no dependencies:

```py
import csv, os


def get_csv_writer(path):
    csv_file = open(path, newline="", mode="w")
    return csv.writer(csv_file), csv_file


rowsize = 100
in_csv = "test.csv"
number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(in_csv)))


with open(in_csv, newline="", mode="r") as foo_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(foo_csv)
    header = reader.__next__()
    filenum = 1
    csv_dir = "split_csv"
    os.mkdir(csv_dir)
    filename = f"foo{filenum}.csv"
    path = os.path.join(csv_dir, filename)
    csv_writer, csv_file = get_csv_writer(path)
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i % rowsize == 0 and i != 0:
            csv_file.close()
            filenum += 1
            filename = f"foo{filenum}.csv"
            path = os.path.join(csv_dir, filename)
            csv_writer, csv_file = get_csv_writer(path)
            csv_writer.writerow(header)
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Here's what that looks like on my machine:

[image]

Note that each file has 101 rows because the header is the first row.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! i found it very handy doing with no libs too. Im gonna try this way too

Comment: Glad it helped! Pandas is awesome, so do whatever works best for you! I just haven't gotten that far in my Python journey yet (still exploring the stdlib).

Comment: for some reason it always gives me this FILE NOT FOUND ERROR, even though it is in the same directory as the program. I also tried utilizing the absolute path since C: and it stills gives me the same error. On line "number_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(in_csv)))"
it tells me the file does not exist when trying to get "in_csv"

do you know what it could be?

Comment: That's really strange. Have you looked into using the pathlib module instead of using a raw string for the filename? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `range` instead of an integer in order to skip rows while keeping the header. In this case you'll also want to start `i` at 1 instead of 0.

```py
for i in range(1, number_lines, rowsize):

    df = pd.read_csv(in_csv,
                     nrows=rowsize,  # number of rows to read at each loop
                     skiprows=range(1, i))  # skip rows that have been read
```

Additionally, you only need to create the output directory once, so you should do that before the loop. Just move the "Subdir maker" section to before the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm gonna try it today

Answer (score 0):

Setting the first row as the "Index" will hold it in place in the Data Frame (df).

Below is a line of code that you can insert once your data is in in the df but before you start manipulating it further:

```
df.set_index('Title', inplace=True) # sets the 'Title of column' as the index value
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try specifying `header` in `pd.read_csv`

```
df = pd.read_csv(in_csv,
                 header=0
                 nrows=rowsize,  # number of rows to read at each loop
                 skiprows=i)  # skip rows that have been read
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i'm gonna try it today

Comment: This will not work--the `header` index is relative to the rows read by Pandas, not the rows in the file, so if you skip *n* rows, `header=0` will try to use row *n* as the header.